# Converting from Joda to Java time

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time, localdatetime, joda-convert

I need to convert joda time to Java time but having some issues

My joda time code :
***p.s method is a long type (long argDateString)***

```
DateTime istime = new DateTime(argDateString*1000);

DateTime NormalTime = istime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("UTC"));

return normalTime.toString();
```

My Java code :

```
Date istime = new date(argDateString*1000);

DateFormat normalTime =  DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.Full, DateFormat.Full);

Return normalTime.format(istime);
```

With Joda I was getting

```
1970-01-15T05:45:05.000Z
```

With Java I am getting

```
15 January 1970 05:45:05 o'clock UTC
```

So is there a way to get what i was getting with Joda time ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and properly format your post, e.g. by using a code block, correcting typos (`new Date(...)` instead of `new date(...)` etc.). Also note that you shouldn't be using classes like `Date` which belong to the _old_ date api. Instead, use the `java.time` classes, e.g. `LocalDate`, `ZoneDateTime` etc.

Comment: Btw, have a look at the available standard formats for time: what Joda is returning seems to be the ISO time format.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date` and `DateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You may also involve `ZoneOffset.UTC`, `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.Instant
.ofEpochSecond(
    Long.parseLong( input )
)
.toString()
```

## Details

Never use `Date` and `DateFormat` classes. These are terribly flawed, and are now legacy. They were supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. The *java.time* framework is the official successor to the *Joda-Time* project, both being led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.

Your first bit of code makes no sense: `argDateString*1000`. Strings cannot be multiplied.

I suspect your text holds a number of seconds since the first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC. If so, use `Long` class to parse to a `long` primitive.

```
long seconds = Long.parseLong( input ) ;  // Parse text into a number.
```

Pass that number to a static factory method for `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( seconds ) ;
```

Now you have an object whose value represents a moment, a point on the timeline, as seen in UTC.

To generate text in your desired standard ISO 8601 format, merely call `toString`. The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when generating/parsing text.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

All this has been covered many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.